# C++ Binary search tree remove segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, binary-search-tree

I was trying to create a bst function for removing.However, I am struggling with this for many hours but I could not figure out what causes to segmentation fault. Can somebody help me to find out please? Here is my code;

```
bool Set::remove(const ItemType & item) {   
    return removeHelper(root, item);    
}


bool Set::removeHelper(Node *root, const ItemType &item) {    
    if (root == NULL) {//check if root is null
        return false;
    }
    else if (item == root->data) {//check if item equals to root
        Node *temp = root;  
        if (root->right == NULL && root->left == NULL) {//check if roots equal to null
            root = NULL;
        }   
        else if (root->right == NULL) {//check if root equals to null
            root = root->left;
        }

        else if (root->left == NULL) {//check if root equals to null
            root = root->right;
        }    
        else {
            Node *p = root; //it is like parent root
            temp = temp->right;    
            while (temp->left != NULL) {//check if temp root equals to null
                p = temp;
                temp = p->left;
            }    
            if (p == root) {//check if root equals to parent
                p->right = temp->right;
            }
            else {
                p->left = temp->right;
            }
            root->data = temp->data;
        }
        delete temp;//delete temp node
        return true;
    }    
    else if (item < root->data)
        removeHelper(root->left, item);//call recursive delete function    
    else if (item > root->data)
        removeHelper(root->right, item);//call recursive delete function    
    return false;
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `removeHelper` function is assigning new values to its `root` parameter, but those new values are lost when the function returns. As you want to change the value of the variable used to call the `removeHelper` function, you should pass it by reference.

```
bool Set::removeHelper(Node * &root, const ItemType &item) {
```

then the changes to the node pointer value will be reflected in the calling function.

Also note `root`is a **really** bad name for your parameter, as it is hiding the class member variable `root`, which makes it very confusing to read. I would suggest changing it to something to `node`. e.g.:

```
bool Set::removeHelper(Node * &node, const ItemType &item) {
```

and of course, changing all the `root` references to `node`

Comment: Thank you so much! You helped a lot